# How to make 1st bar selected in column highchart on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, click

I have one simple column highchart. When i clicked on any bar from column chart then it is selected. But i also want by default 1st bar should be get selected.

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
```

I got this object on page load

```
chart.series[0].data[0]
```

How to make 1st bar selected as i need to change its colour and need to call one function also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `point.select()` function.

So in your case, either in the chart load event, or externally after loading the chart, use:

```
chart.series[0].data[0].select();
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j8m8d9vd/

References:

- Chart Load Event: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load
- Point Select Function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.select